# Variable treated unexpectedly in Makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have `Makefile` below that treats `$(CC)` varaible as `cc`. Variable `$(BB)` is treated `gcc` as expected. Why `$(CC)` is treated as `cc` and not `gcc`?

```
#
# Makefile

BB ?= gcc
CC ?= gcc
LVGL_DIR ?= ${shell pwd}
CFLAGS ?= -Wall -Wshadow -Wundef -Wmaybe-uninitialized -O3 -g0 -I$(LVGL_DIR)/
# LDFLAGS ?= -lSDL2 -lm
LDFLAGS ?= -lm
BUILDDIR := build
BINDIR := bin
BIN = $(BINDIR)/output


#Collect the files to compile
MAINSRC = ./main.c

include $(LVGL_DIR)/lvgl/lvgl.mk
include $(LVGL_DIR)/lv_drivers/lv_drivers.mk

#include 
INC := -I . -I lvgl -I lv_drivers

#CSRCS +=$(LVGL_DIR)/mouse_cursor_icon.c

OBJEXT ?= .o

AOBJS = $(ASRCS:.S=$(OBJEXT))
COBJS = $(CSRCS:.c=$(OBJEXT))
# AOBJS = $(patsubst %,%,$(ASRCS:.S=$(OBJEXT)))

#reference
# SOURCES := $(shell find . -type f -iname "*.$(SRCEXT)" )
# OBJECTS := $(patsubst %,%,$(SOURCES:.$(SRCEXT)=.o))

MAINOBJ = $(MAINSRC:.c=$(OBJEXT))

SRCS = $(ASRCS) $(CSRCS) $(MAINSRC)
OBJS = $(AOBJS) $(COBJS)

## MAINOBJ -> OBJFILES

all: default
%.o: %.c
    @echo "TEST $(CC) $(BB) $<"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC) -c $< -o $@
    
    
default: $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(MAINOBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN) $(MAINOBJ) $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(LDFLAGS)

clean: 
    rm -f $(BIN) $(AOBJS) $(COBJS) $(MAINOBJ)
```

UPD

If I comment `#CC ?= gcc` then it is still treated as `cc`.  In case I run command `echo $CC`  nothing is printed. So who sets `CC` to `cc` ?

Comment: [`?=`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_003f_003d) will only set the variable if it isn't already set.  The results you are seeing suggest that the variable `CC` is already set in your shell.

Comment: Yes, if I comment `#CC ?= gcc` then it is still treated as `cc`.  In case run command `echo $CC ` nothing is printed. So who sets `CC` to `cc` ?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BB ?= gcc
CC ?= gcc

all:
    echo $(CC)
    echo $(BB)
```

will work fine

```
> make
echo cc
cc         # default value is being picked up
echo gcc
gcc
```

However, if you already have `CC` in env or you pass `CC` as argument it will pick existing value

```
> make CC=aa
echo aa
aa
echo gcc
gcc
```

or like this

```
> export CC=dd
> make
echo dd
dd
echo gcc
gcc
```

also, note that `GNU Make` has lots of defaults defined inside it's `src/default.c` - `CC` is one of those.

```
#ifdef GCC_IS_NATIVE
    "CC", "gcc",
#else
    "CC", "cc",
#endif
```

Comment: Where `src/default.c` is located? I can't find such file in my device?

Comment: You have to download `GNU Make` source code from here: `http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/`. Also, take a look at comment by Mat, where he posted link to docs with default values.